# PublicKeyToken and pfx file

Tags: .net, pfx, strongname

I'm signing my assemblies with pfx file.
Today I've changed the pfx file which has expired and after signing assembly with
new one it changed the PublicKeyToken of my assembly and because I've got 
a lot of serialized data my app. stoppped working. Is it ok that new pfx file changed PublicKeyToken? I suppose that it must be the same and must not depend on certificate expiration and renewal.

Thanks in advace.

Comment: It seems that private keys of these pfx files are different. So they produce different PublicKeyToken...

Comment: you refreshed your expired PFX or you bought a new one?

Comment: I supposed that admins refreshed pfx file, but instead they got the new one (private keys are different -- an old pfx-file has 1024 bits and new one has 2048 bits). Never mind, I resolved my problem.

Comment: Your admins did the right thing. It is recommended that we use 2048 from 2010 onwards.

Comment: I resolved my issue: first of all I had to understand difference between sn.exe and signtool.exe. I sign my **assembly** with old pfx and sn.exe, and sign my **code** with new pfx file and signtool.exe.